# is there API for past NOAA weather forecasts (forecast archive)?

Tags: weather-api, noaa

I'm looking for a source for old weather forecasts--yesterdays, last months, last years. For major cities in US. 
Seems like it's easy to find *future forecasts*, and *historical actual data*, but not *historical forecasts*.

Comment: You may get better answers for this on the beta site earthscience.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

The product you're probably looking for is the [National Digital Forecast Database](https://digital.weather.gov), the [gridded system the NWS uses to input most of its forecast](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/ndfd_home).  There's no API that I know of, but there are archived data files in places like [here](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/ndfd_home).  [This NWS page on degrib](https://www.weather.gov/mdl/degrib_pastwx) also offers some potential hints on what you may need.

The NWS does still also issue some specific point forecasts for certain locations, specialized forecasts for events like fires, plus forecast discussions, warning text, etc.  If those are the types of things you are looking for, it may be a bit more of a slog to dig through and piece together [find the product identifiers](https://forecast.weather.gov/product_types.php?site=NWS) and archive resources you want.  Iowa State offers a [tool for accessing some of the past data](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/wx/afos/#), but only [by office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Weather_Service_Weather_Forecast_Offices).  You also may want to dig into some of the text products on [their MTArchive site](http://mtarchive.geol.iastate.edu), particularly perhaps the Public files - the specific data is less organized, yet the simple layout may make it more straightforward to find what you need.  [This StormTrack thread](https://stormtrack.org/community/threads/nws-text-product-archive.8858/) may offer one final rabbit trail towards finding archives of NWS text products.

As mentioned in comments, you may also find there are additional users with useful input on the [Earth Science Stack Exchange Beta community](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com).